Unable to Connect to Ubuntu Server on Windows Subsystem from Remote Desktop
I'm currently running Ubuntu on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and have set up OpenSSH Server on my Ubuntu virtual machine. I want to connect to this server using Remote Desktop from another machine, but I'm facing issues.
Here's what I've done so far:

Installed and started OpenSSH Server on my Ubuntu running on WSL.
Checked that the SSH service is running using sudo service ssh status.
Verified that my Windows firewall is configured to allow SSH connections.

However, when I try to connect remotely using an SSH client or Remote Desktop, I can't seem to establish a connection. I'm getting connection timeouts or refusal errors.
Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue? Is there something I might be missing in my configuration?
Thank you in advance!
